# Get options of custom shipping method

Tags: magento-enterprise, shipping, model, shipping-methods

How can I get the options of a custom shipping method. I couldn't really find anything useful. Only that:

```
$shippingmethods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config');
        foreach($shippingmethods as $code =>$carrier) {
            if ($code == 'my_shipping_metho')
                //do something1
        }
```

But `$shippingmethods` is always empty and therefore I never enter the `foreach`.

and that:

```
$shippingMethods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
        $shippingMethods['my_shipping_method'];
```

But here I don't have any useful data. Just ID and store.

So, I have a shipping method, which has options for certain kilograms. And I want to get the minimum weight of that method. I know the `code` of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the options created in admin for a shipping method please use following code:

```
$carriers_selected = Mage::getStoreConfig('config_mode/namespaces/myuser');
```

like see the xml format for system.xml

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <config_mode>
            <groups>
                <namespaces translate="label" module="ship"> 
                 <myuser translate="label">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </myuser>
```

Hope you find a solution its working for me